# js - why is await not throwing error when used outside function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following syntax:

```
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });

    console.log(`[MONGODB CONNECTED]: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`[ERROR]: ${error.message}`.red.underline.bold);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

and I've used it like this:

await connectDB();
console.log("print after connection");

*it actually works*, I thought I could use await keyword only inside an `async` function, however, no error is being thrown, and the database actually connects before printing the test message. Is this a legal code or I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: You must be in a module in an environment that supports top-level `await`

Comment: I actually have no idea on this, how am I in a module? And what would be a top level await? Could you give me a pointer?

Comment: Did you type that in the console?

Comment: You're in a module if something is `import`ing your file, or if you have `type="module` on the web, etc.

Comment: @Kaiido , no, that's from a file